# `Right 5` in Haskell and Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

In `ghci`, I ran:

```
ghci> :t Right 5
Right 5 :: Num b => Either a b
```

What's the meaning of `a`?

How does it compare with Scala's version?

```
scala> Right(5)
res0: scala.util.Right[Nothing,Int] = Right(5)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`a` is, like `b` in this example, a type variable. It can be instantiated with any type (whereas `b` can be instantiated with any type that satisfies the constraint that it is also an instance of `Num`).

The scala example works quite differently due to scala's type system being quite different; There is no real concept of a value ever having a not fully instantiated type, so you need to assign a type to the `Left` possibility of your `Either` value. Barring further constraints, this just ends up being `Nothing`. Due to the way scala's type system works (`Nothing` being a subtype of any other type, so you can think of it as a dual to the `Any` type) an `Either[Nothing,B]` is also an `Either[A,B]`  for any `A`.

Comment: Just wanted to note that `Any` and `Nothing` are dual in that they are exact opposites: `Any`is the universal super type, `Nothing` is the universal subtype. Naturally, no value can be of type `Nothing`: perfect for describing the left portion of a `Right`!